# Floats rounded down in AWS AppSync VTL

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl, aws-appsync-resolver

I am creating a resolvers response mapping in AWS AppSync which is meant to perform a math calculation and return a percentage value as a float:

```
#set( $result = $ctx.source.total * 100 / 365000 )
$result
```

However VTL rounds this down each time to the nearest whole number such as `1.0`, `2.0` etc.

Given `5000 * 100 / 365000`:

Expected - `1.36`
Result - `1.0`

Is there anyway I can achieve this? or do I need to look towards using a Lambda (which feels overkill for something so simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$ctx.source.total`, `100`, and `365000` are all treated as integers (java.lang.Integer) by VTL.

VTL does support floating point numbers via java.lang.Double. The VTL syntax for a double instead of an integer is just `100.0` instead of `100`.

If any of the numbers in the assignment are doubles,`$result` will be a double.

So you could do this and get `1.36986301369863`:

```
#set( $result = $ctx.source.total * 100.0 / 365000 )
```

Here's a link to some examples and example output:

https://mappingtool.dev/app/appsync/3d44255e560fa075b45bfa08afbb6fe4

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the example above, the result would be 1.0 because 1.36 is rounded down to 1.0. To return the result as a float, you can use the Math.round() function and divide the result by 100:

```
#set( $result = Math.round($ctx.source.total * 100 / 365000) / 100 )
$result
```

This will return the result as a float with 2 decimal places.

---

To solve this problem, without using a Lambda and without using the Math.round() function, you can use the following VTL:

```
#set( $result = $ctx.source.total * 100 / 365000 )
#set( $result = $util.parseJson($util.toJson($result)) )
$result
```

This will return the result as a float with 2 decimal places.